# Instancia entre formularios y clases c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, formularios

Necesito ayuda en esta parte, lo que trato dehacer es pasar objetos entre formularios, y aqui estoy tratando de pasar del formulairo 3 al 2, solo que ya que al momento de asignar Form2 formPadre;
me apare este error:
[image: Error]

Y esta parte es como la tengo en Form2
[image: form2]

Comment: Hola Emilio, bienvenido a Stackoverflow, te invito a realizar el [tour] del sitio para ver como funcionamos y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También te recomiendo pasar por [ask] para ver como elaborar una pregunta de calidad y que esta sea bien recibida, por lo general, las preguntas en las que se adjuntan capturas no son bien recibidas y se suelen cerrar, Stackoverflow tiene su manera para formatear el código, considera editar tu pregunta para que podamos ayudarte. Un saludo.

Comment: Porfavor, copia el código en la pregunta, evita el uso de capturas con código, esto dificulta a la gente que quiere ayudarte y también a la gente que posteriormente tenga una duda similar a la tuya

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es inicializar el form que quieres utilizar, por ejemplo.

```
Form3 formulario=new Form3(); 
formulario.TrabajadorForm2=trabajador;
```

El error que te indica visual studio, es que la variable formPadre es null por que no ha sido referenciado. Ahora si no me equivoco en tu codigo, lo que alcanzo a ver es que lo tienes como una propiedad, pero no lo asignas a la variable.

```
public FormPadre{set;get;}
```

Me imagino que lo que querias hacer es

```
private Form formPadre;
public Form FormPadre
{
 set {formPadre=value;}
 get {return formPadre;}
}
```

Comment: Tiene que recibir la referencia en `Form3`, si crea una instancia nueva, el dato no se va a modificar en el formulario original..